# How to split a list by comma in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, csv, split

I was trying to read a `csv` file and split the data by comma.

I used

```
IFS=, list=($line)
for word in ${list[@]}; do
  echo $word
done
```

to split the `csv` record based on comma, which works fine.

The issue is when I have a quoted string in the csv which contains a comma

```
Name, "Oct 2, 2015 at 1:06 PM", Superman
```

In this scenario it returns

```
Name
"Oct 2
 2015 at 1:06 PM"
Superman
```

Whereas I want

```
Name
"Oct 2, 2015 at 1:06 PM"
Superman
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Instead, use a proper parser in Python, Perl...

Comment: `apt-get install csvtool` ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a good way to do this in pure bash, and you can't use `cut` to do it, which also doesn't respect quotes.

There are good command-line utilities around that do it, though. Fedora has a `csv` package, for instance, that provides a `csv` command that does the same sort of thing as `cut` but respecting quotes:

```
[james@marlon ~] $ echo '1,"3,w",4' | csv --col 2
"3,w"
```

It also provides a package `ocaml-csv`, which gives you `csvtool` with similar functionality:

```
[james@marlon ~] $ echo '1,"3,w",4' | csvtool col 2 -
"3,w"
```

These are very likely to be available on other distros too.