# Need to extract a substring and assign it to a new variable without using echo

Tags: bash

I need to extract sub-strings and set them as new strings without using `echo`.

My original variable is delimited by commas, so I have that going for me, but I can't use `echo` so I don't think I can use `cut`.

I think I need to use the [method shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482947/3271649) but I'm not quite getting it

```
myvar="1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

I think it's something along the lines of:

```
one=${myvar%%,}
two=${myvar}
```

Comment: Check [How to split a list by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323299/how-to-split-a-list-by-comma-in-bash-script).

Comment: sweet! that was easy. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just to leave an answer here:

```
IFS=',' read a b c d <<< '1,2,3,4'
echo $a $b $c $d
1 2 3 4
```

For a more detailed explanation, check [how to split a list by comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323299/how-to-split-a-list-by-comma-in-bash-script).

Comment: or `IFS=',' read -a arr <<< $myvar` to read all fields into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the slicing from the method you linked:

```
myvar="1,2,3,4,5"
one=${myvar::1}
two=${myvar:2:1}
three=${myvar:4:1}
```

Or if you aren't sure of the indexes:

```
# grab the first one
one=${myvar%%,*}
rest=${myvar#*,}
two=${rest%%,*}
# and so on
```